# How do you evolve Sliggoo in Pokemon Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I was told to level it up in the rain and did, but it did not evolve. I checked again and leveled it up again, still no evolving. How do I evolve him?

Comment: Did you level in naturally occurring rain or did you have a Pokemon use Rain Dance or induce rain through some other method?

Answer (score 5):

Sliggoo evolves into Goodra starting at level 50 if it is raining in the overworld. Rain caused by *Rain Dance* or *Drizzle* will **not** trigger the evolution.

Here are some places where you can find overworld rain:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sliggoo evolves when levelling up during naturally occurring rain starting at level 50.